# How in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 to rollback easily?

Tags: rollback, ssms

I'm used to setting Oracle's tools to not auto-commit, run statements, then click a 'rollback' button if I'm not happy with the result. I'm hoping I'm overlooking something in Microsoft's tool...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you can do it by `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` (also with `SET ANSI_DEFAULTS ON` for connection.